# How to display the name of Item in Material-UI Data Grid

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, mui-x

Am using DataGrid from material UI react to display my data.

my database is like this:

[image]

this is my column code

```
const columns = [
      { field: 'user_id', headerName: 'User',flex: 1},
      { field: 'item_id', headerName: 'Item',flex: 1},
      { field: 'status', headerName: 'Status',flex: 1},
      { field: 'prepared_by', headerName: 'Prepared By',flex: 1},
      { field: 'date_ordered', headerName: 'Date Ordered',flex: 1},
      { field: 'date_received', headerName: 'Date Received',flex: 1},
    ];
```

current output

[image]

I tried this one but its showing blank

```
{ field: 'user_id.name', headerName: 'User',flex: 1},
```

Hope someone can help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can map your data and add new property as field of column

sth like this :

```
<DataGrid
          rows={data.map(item=>({
            ...item,
            username:item.user_id?.name
          }))}
...
```

and new column row :

```
 { field: 'username', headerName: 'User',flex: 1},
```